# Ionic 3 control slides in another page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I Have my slides in one page, where in my slides are other pages. I want to make that if I click on button in that other page - slide would go next  :

**slides-page.ts**

```js
@ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

goNext() {
  this.slides.slideNext()
}
```

**slides-page.html**

```html
<ion-slides (click)="goNext()" (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged()" [pager]="true">
  <ion-slide>
    <page-family-status></page-family-status>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <page-familymembers></page-familymembers>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

For example if I am in slide 1 - page-family-status. If I click in that page button - next it would slide to second slide - page-familymembers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an event Emitter in `page-family-status` and emit an event on button click

```
@Output()
buttonClicked: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

click(){
    this.buttonClicked.emit(true);
}
```

and then in the parent component you subscribe to the emitter and excute slide.next

```
<page-family-status (buttonClicked)="goNext() "></page-family-status>
```